# TYPO3 7.6 / Powermail 3.2: Mapping of new field properties won't work

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I'm trying to add a new Powermail field property as explained [here](https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/ForDevelopers/AddNewFieldProperties.md) and to get the value after a formular is submitted using a [Finisher](https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/ForDevelopers/AddFinisherClasses.md)

The new property can be used in TYPO3 Backend without any problem and is shown in the Database, but there seems to be a problem with the mapping of the Domain Model as I can't see the new added field property when using my Finisher (and for instance using a "var_dump" on the "Mail"-Class).

**ext_tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE tx_powermail_domain_model_field (
    my_new_property varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

**ext_tables.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tx_powermail_domain_model_field', array(
    'my_new_property' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'Mapping',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'items' => array(
                array('none', ''),
                array('test1', 'test1'),
                array('test2', 'test2'),
            ),
        ),
    )
));

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tx_powermail_domain_model_field',
    '--div--;MyNewTab,my_new_property'
);
```

**setup.txt**

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            In2code\Powermail\Domain\Model\Form {
                subclasses {
                    0 = TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Form
                }
            }
            In2code\Powermail\Domain\Model\Page {
                subclasses {
                    0 = TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Page
                }
            }
            In2code\Powermail\Domain\Model\Field {
                subclasses {
                    0 = TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Field
                }
            }
            TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Form {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_powermail_domain_model_form
                }
            }
            TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Page {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_powermail_domain_model_page
                }
            }
            TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Field {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_powermail_domain_model_field
                }
            }
        }
        objects {
            In2code\Powermail\Domain\Repository\FormRepository.className = TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Repository\FormRepository
        }
    }
}

//Finisher
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup {
    finishers {
        1 {
            class = TYPO3\Myextension\Finisher\MyNewFinisher
        }
    }
}
```

**Field.php**

```
<?php

namespace TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model;

/**
 * Class Field
 *
 * @package TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model
 */
class Field extends \In2code\Powermail\Domain\Model\Field
{
    /**
     * myNewProperty
     *
     * @var string $myNewProperty
     */
    protected $myNewProperty;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMyNewProperty()
    {
        return $this->myNewProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $myNewProperty
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setMyNewProperty($myNewProperty)
    {
        $this->myNewProperty = $myNewProperty;
    }

}
```

**Page.php**

```
<?php

namespace TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage;

/**
 * Class Page
 * @package TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model
 */
class Page extends \In2code\Powermail\Domain\Model\Page
{
    /**
     * Powermail Fields
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Field>
     */
    protected $fields = null;

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $fields
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFields($fields)
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;
    }

    /**
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage
     */
    public function getFields()
    {
        return $this->fields;
    }
}
```

**Form.php**

```
<?php

namespace TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage;

/**
 * Class Form
 * @package TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model
 */
class Form extends \In2code\Powermail\Domain\Model\Form

{
    /**
     * pages
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Page>
     */
    protected $pages;

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $pages
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPages($pages)
    {
        $this->pages = $pages;
    }

    /**
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage
     */
    public function getPages()
    {
        return $this->pages;
    }
}
```

**FormRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Repository;

/**
 * Class FormRepository
 *
 * @package TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Repository
 */
class FormRepository extends \In2code\Powermail\Domain\Repository\FormRepository
{

}
```

Just for reference the Finisher class, where I'm trying to get the new property. When I'm var dumping the "Mail", I only get the standard Powermail Fields, without my new property.

**MyNewFinisher**

```
<?php

namespace TYPO3\Myextension\Finisher;

use In2code\Powermail\Domain\Model\Mail;
use In2code\Powermail\Finisher\AbstractFinisher;

class MyNewFinisher extends AbstractFinisher
{

    /**
     * @var Mail
     */
    protected $mail;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $configuration;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $settings;


    /**
     * MyFinisher
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function myFinisher()
    {

//        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this->getMail());die();


    }

}
```

Sorry for the long description... Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Try clearing TYPO3 install tool cache and then if this is a composer-based instance, do an auto dump or else do the same from the install tool and (re-) dump autoload information for all active third-party extensions.